Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия пользователем на кнопки, бот сохранял информацию и потом выдавал текст?
И еще надо сделать так, чтобы когда человек нажимал number и вводил номер какой то ,бот это сохранял и также вкладывал в текст в конце.
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Сourier")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Guest')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi! Choose courier or guest", reply_markup=markup)

@ bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == 'Сourier':
     markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
     btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Car")
     btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Without car')
     btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
     markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Car or without car", reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Car':
     markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
     btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Number")
     markup.add(btn1)
     bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Please enter number|Example:В238ТР37", reply_markup=markup)


    elif message.text == 'Without car':
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ok,thank you!")

    elif message.text == 'Back':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Сourier")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Guest')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi! Choose courier or guest", reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling()


"...какой то бот это сохранял и также вкладывал в текст в конце." - что за?!

Ну короче мне нужно сделать так. Человек заходит в бота выбирает курьер или гость после выбора,человек выбирает за рулем или пеший,в случае если за рулем человек нажимает number и вводит любой номер машины, потом надо сделать так чтоб бот спросил марку машины. И надо сделать так чтобы в конце выходило как то так:  Курьер, за рулем, в999вв77, audi или же гость, пеший. Максимально сложно объяснить, но я только учусь делать такое. Извините за неразборчивый вопрос. @Amgarak

Вам нужно воспользоваться bot.register_next_step_handler()
